# How to programmatically add an UILabel to my UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom UICollectionViewCell and it has a scrollView as its child. I want to programmatically add 
an UILabel to the scrollView.

```
class MyUICollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell {
    var newLabel = UILabel?
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        var labelFrame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 439, width: 355, height:0);
        newLabel = UILabel(frame: labelFrame)

        self.scrollView.addSubview(newLabel!)
    }
}
```

I tried doing it in the init() or init(code aDecoder :NSCoder) method. But I get an exception saying my scrollView is nil.  Can you please tell me where is the best place to add my UILabel?

Comment: Where are you creating the scrollView?

Comment: It is created in Storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the label in awakeForNib. IBOutlets are still nil at the time an init method is called.